# Android set text values of xml layout from java

Tags: java, android, xml, json

I am trying to set the values of the android:text from the java code, while the program is running. It is intended to be a schedule program, and after the user logs in, I need to set the values of the text in the listview. The data is being read from a local JSON file, but from there, I am not sure what to do about setting the text values from the code.

Thanks,
Androidonly42

Comment: You need to read about Adapters and findViewById first, then try, then ask here.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it shows no research effort or attempt at solving the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ListAdapter. Please have a look at the link below

You can download sample code and have a look
http://www.androidhive.info/2011/10/android-listview-tutorial/

List adapter is explained here
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html

Answer (score 0):

You could use an `Adapter`, and once you have new data from your JSON file, update the model then call `notifyDataSetChanged` (on the UI thread), to refresh the content of your `ListView`.
Also, have a look [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html).